# How to close multiple edge browser gracefully?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, browser, microsoft-edge

How to close multiple edge browser gracefully ? Thanks!

I try to close multiple edge browser gracefully , but just close one edge main window.

I avoid use Kill() ,because it causes unexpected error to recover.

```
Dim myProcessesList As New List(Of Process)
myProcessesList.AddRange(Process.GetProcessesByName("msedge"))
    For Each instance As Process In myProcessesList
        If instance.ProcessName = "msedge" And instance.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
           instance.CloseMainWindow()
    Next
```

I expect that no matter how many main Edge windows are open, they will close gracefully , Thanks !

Comment: I can't think of other solutions other than `Kill()`. I suggest you can check if Microsoft Edge WebDriver can meet your requirements. It can automate Edge browser. Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/.